# App update losing all data as Code/Resouce path for pkg changes

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-package-managers

We recently submitted an update of our to Google Play, and have had a handful of users report an issue with all of their data disappearing.

We've managed to reproduce the issue once, and it was caused by:

```
5787 08-17 12:50:56.309 937 1030 W PackageManager: Code path for pkg : com.attidomobile.passwallet changing from /data/app/com.attidomobile.passwallet-2 to /data/app/com.attidomobile.passwallet-1

5789 08-17 12:50:56.309 937 1030 W PackageManager: Resource path for pkg : com.attidomobile.passwallet changing from /data/app/com.attidomobile.passwallet-2 to /data/app/com.attidomobile.passwallet-1
```

Note, this is not the same problem as [Resource/Code path changing for pkg on Android App update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604119/resource-code-path-changing-for-pkg-on-android-app-update). We are ProGuarding our app, but the actual folder it's being installed to is changing.

Anyone experienced this, or know of the reasons why the PackageManager changes the code/resource path?

I found this post describing the update process for pre-installed applications which seems to match what is happening, but our app isn't a pre-installed app:

http://debuggingisfun.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/android-3rd-party-application-as-system.html

We've gone through the changes between versions and there have been no significant changes; the only change in the manifest is to the version number, plus some logic changes in the code.

We've never seen this issue before with any of our previous app updates (and there's been a lot, the app is nearly 3 years old and this is update 38).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue. I can reproduce it by moving app to sd and then updating it. The same logcat output shows up and the app data is cleared.